# How to use AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM in android

Tags: java, android, alarm, android-alarms

Here's code that's supposed to dismiss the alarm by it's label:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_DISMISS_ALARM);

    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_ALARM_SEARCH_MODE, AlarmClock.ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_LABEL);
    //intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.ALARM_SEARCH_MODE_TIME,1);
    //intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_IS_PM, true);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Label");
    if(intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(SetAlarmActivity.this, "There is no app that support this action", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Unfortunately, it just opens the default alarm app and doesn't even dismiss the alarm I need. How to make it work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

That code is doing what it's supposed to do.  It's opening the intent you specified-  the alarm clock app.

I'm assuming you set an alarm via AlarmManager and want to cancel that?  If so, the code is:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                                 getApplicationContext(), REQUEST_CODE, myIntent, 0);

alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
```

Make sure the request code is the same as you started.

If you actually set an alarm via the alarm app and wanted to cancel it-  I'm not sure there is a way without involving the user.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I set the alarm via AlarmClock.SET_ALARM

Comment: Then you need the user to intent, and the alarm clock decided it wants to ask the user to confirm the deletion.  There's no way around that.